# How to ignore duplicate name and make first letter should be caps using nested array?

Tags: php

Hi Friends I am using nested array for displaying name and languages.I want to display the fist letter name should be in caps and avoid the language duplicate.This is my code.
**My code**

```
$user=array(array("name"=>"prusoth","language"=>array("english","tamil")),array("name"=>"ven kat","language"=>array("english","french")));

print_r($user);

print_r(array_unique($user));

print_r(ucfirst($user));
```

I want the output like this:
 name = (Prusoth,Venkat)
 language = (english,tamil,french)

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your arrays into 2 arrays: keys and values:

```
$names = array_keys($user);
$countries = array_values($user);
```

Uppercase each element of names array:

```
array_map('ucfirst', $names);
```

Unique countries:

```
$countries = array_unique($countries);
```